# How to extract a substring using regex python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string .I want to extract the substring which starts with a number and ends with a number in that substring.

MY string is `"05/24/2019  04:33 PM               582 atm1.py"`

I tried with the below pattern 
`^\d.+\s+\d$`

```
i="05/24/2019  04:33 PM               582 atm1.py"    
print(re.match("^\d.+\s+\d$",i))
```

Expected o/p=`"05/24/2019  04:33 PM               582"`
Actual o/p=the entire string I am getting.

Comment: You are not getting the entire string... `\d$` wouldn't match in your case since the string does not end with a digit thus you get `None` as match. Either your input or your regex is different from what you have shown here.

Answer (score 0):

A very sensitive pattern:

```
print(re.match("\d+/\d+/\d+\s+\d+:\d+\s+PM\s+\d+",i).group(0))
```

Or use:

```
print(re.match(".+\s+",i).group(0))
```

Output:

```
05/24/2019  04:33 PM               582
```

Comment: @Sam The second one

Comment: `".+\s+"` is not a valid pattern as it will take any initial character, not only a number as specified, and will end in the last space, not in a number as specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex: `"\d[\d\s:APM/]*\d"`

```py
import re

s = "05/24/2019  04:33 PM               582 atm1.py"
pattern = "\d[\d\s:APM/]*\d"
print(re.match(pattern, s).group(0))
```

Regex breakdown:
 1. `\d`: a decimal character (0-9)
 2. `[\d\s:APM/]*`: the `*` means any number of the characters inside the square brackets. Inside the square brackets we have `\d` for decimals (0-9), `\s` for spaces, and `:APM/` for those literal characters (`:` for the time, `APM` for AM and PM, and `/` for the date).
 3. `\d`: a decimal character (0-9)

Outputs: `05/24/2019  04:33 PM               582`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nDrIIQ/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a substring that starts with the first number as whole word and ends with the last number as whole from a longer string, you may use

```
r'\b\d+\b.*\b\d+\b'
```

**Details**

- `\b\d+\b` - a word boundary, digit and a word boundary (no digits, letters or underscores before and after are allowed)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars (without `re.DOTALL` or `re.S` flag, only matching non-linebreak chars), as many as possible
- `\b\d+\b` - a word boundary, digit and a word boundary (no digits, letters or underscores before and after are allowed)

In Python, use

```
import re
i="05/24/2019  04:33 PM               582 atm1.py"
m = re.search(r'\b\d+\b.*\b\d+\b', i)
if m:
    print(m.group()) # => 05/24/2019  04:33 PM               582
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vetaiC).